# Is it possible to reverse engineer to know the format without .proto

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is it possible to reverse engineer to know the format without .proto
I'm trying to read the API response and have this challenge.
The content-type is protobuf and I able to get the content in HEX.
After tried some protobuf decoder then I can get the value of the proto's content. The API also support content format in json so I able to compare and the values matched.

HEX response's content (from Charles Proxy)

```
00000000  0a 00 12 1b 09 00 00 00 00 00 80 56 40 11 00 00              V@   
00000010  00 00 00 20 bc 40 19 00 00 00 00 00 20 9c 40           @        @
```

Proto Buffer Decorder:

```
[0a] 1 string: (0): 
[12] 2 string: (27): 
    [09] 1 fixed64/double: 4636033603912859648 (0x4056800000000000) (90.000000)
    [11] 2 fixed64/double: 4664638498421080064 (0x40bc200000000000) (7200.000000)
    [19] 3 fixed64/double: 4655631299166339072 (0x409c200000000000) (1800.000000)
```

Response in JSON format:

```
{
    "config": {
        "interval": 90,
        "timeout": 7200,
        "timeout2": 1800
    }
}
```

However, there are some endpoint which don't support JSON so I only have the values but not tag names (such as "config", "timeout" and "timeout2").
Is there a way to reverse engineer the messages to know the format without .proto file?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot definitively disassemble messages without the schema because messages (a) can be ambiguous; (b) don't include message/field names etc.

As you've seen, there are various tools that can help include the protobuf compiler [`protoc`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf).

Producers of public APIs that use protobuf messages will generally publish protos to aid in this process.